# Integer overflow and std::stoi

Tags: c++

if x > INT_MAX or if x > INT_MIN the function will return 0... or that's what i'm trying to do :)

in my test case i pass in a value that is INT_MAX + 1... 2147483648 ... to introduce integer overflow to see how the program handles it.

i step through... my IDE debugger says that the value immediately goes to -2147483648 upon overflow and for some reason the program executes beyond both of these statements:

if (x > INT_MAX)
if (x < INT_MIN)

and keeps crashes at int revInt = std::stoi(strNum);
saying out of range

Must be something simple, but it's got me stumped. Why isn't the program returning before it ever gets to that std::stoi() given x > INT_MAX? Any help appreciated. Thanks! Full listing of function and test bed below: (sorry having trouble with the code insertion formatting..)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> //using namespace std;
class Solution {
public: int reverse(int x)
{

    // check special cases for int and set flags:

    // is x > max int, need to return 0 now
    if(x > INT_MAX)
        return 0;

    // is x < min int, need to return 0 now
    if(x < INT_MIN)
        return 0;

    // is x < 0, need negative sign handled at end

    // does x end with 0, need to not start new int with 0 if it's ploy numeric and the functions used handle that for us

    // do conversion, reversal, output:

    // convert int to string
    std::string strNum = std::to_string(x);

    // reverse string
    std::reverse(strNum.begin(), strNum.end());

    // convert reversed string to int
    int revInt = std::stoi(strNum);

    // multiply by -1 if x was negative
    if (x < 0)
        revInt = revInt * -1;

    // output reversed integer
    return revInt;

}
};
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    // test cases
    // instance Solution and call it's method
    Solution sol;
    int answer = sol.reverse(0); // 0
    std::cout << "in " << 0 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(-1); // -1
    std::cout << "in " << -1 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(10); // 1
    std::cout << "in " << 10 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(12); // 21
    std::cout << "in " << 12 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(100); // 1
    std::cout << "in " << 100 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(123); // 321
    std::cout << "in " << 123 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(-123); // -321
    std::cout << "in " << -123 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(1024); // 4201
    std::cout << "in " << 1024 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(-1024); // -4201
    std::cout << "in " << -1024 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(2147483648); // 0
    std::cout << "in " << 2147483648 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    answer = sol.reverse(-2147483648); // 0
    std::cout << "in " << -2147483648 << ", out " << answer << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How can x be greater than INT_MAX?

Comment: just curious how `(x > INT_MAX)` shall ever evaluate to true if `x` is of type `int`...

Comment: Imagine a 4 decimal digit number display, then these tests are the equivalent of "if the display shows a number greater than 9999"

Comment: Alexei thanks for the formatting help! Others... i'm asking the more obvious question... why is the code getting past those two if statements to crash at the std::stoi function? Are they unable to evaluate... is that what you're saying? Confused. Thanks!

Comment: `stoi()` throws an exception if the conversion would give a value out of range.   It does not give ANY return value in that case.  Testing `x > INT_MAX` will always evaluate to false if `x` is of type `int`.   Converting a value greater than `INT_MAX` to `int` gives (depending on context) either implementation defined or undefined behaviour - either way, the behaviour cannot be relied on.

Comment: Peter thanks, so the statements testing x > INT_MAX or x < INT_MIN should evaluate then? And that means they should immediately return 0 and never get to std::stoi() to evaluate in or out of range ... right? Hence the confusion i'm having? Or is my assumption about return 0 being executed wrong? Thanks!

Comment: On further reflection... hmmm... I see what Neil and Stephen are saying about int vs INT_MAX. Good point.

Comment: @Spanky - You have the logic backward.   `if (x > INT_MAX) return 0;`  will NEVER return zero at that point.   Similarly for `x < INT_MIN`.    Which means your code will always reach the `stoi()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any test like `(x > INT_MAX)` with `x` being of type `int` will never evaluate to true, since the value of `x` cannot exceed `INT_MAX`.

Anyway, even if `2147483647` would be a valid range, its reverse `7463847412` is not.
So I think its better to let `stoi` "try" to convert the values and "catch" any `out_of_range`-exception`. The following code illustrates this approach:

```
int convert() {
    const char* num = "12345678890123424542";
    try {
        int x = std::stoi(num);
        return x;
    } catch (std::out_of_range  &e) {
        cout << "invalid." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```